# java string iterations of char variables

Tags: java

How do I move char characters to left or to right in a string?

Comment: You'll want to first separate the words, which you can do with `split(" ");` as demonstrated in Viswanath's answer below. Then you can process each word separately with the `for` loop you have now. You'll need another (outer) `for` loop to process all the words.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the input string backwards you need to keep every character on an odd index of each word and any blank characters.

You could start with this snippet. See it as a PoC to demonstrate the logic. Optimisations are possible.

```
String encoded = "bxoqb swi eymrawn yim";
StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder();
boolean keep = true;
for (int i = encoded.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (encoded.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        if (keep) {
            decoded.append(encoded.charAt(i));
        }
        keep = !keep;
    } else {
        decoded.append(' ');
        keep = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("decoded = " + decoded);
```

**output**

```
decoded = my name is bob
```

**explanation**

- the `for-loop` processes the string backwards, so the characters are processed as `miy nwarmye iws bqoxb`
- the variable `i` hold the current index position in the string `encoded`
- as we want to keep only the characters on odd positions in a word the variable `keep` is used as a indicator
- when the variable `keep` is `true` we append the current character (the one on position `i` in string `encoded`) to the string buffer `decoded`
- if the current processed character is not a  the value of `keep`is negated (true->false, false->true), so we append characters on every odd position
- as we need to keep  between the words also we have to treat this separately, each  is appended to `decoded` and `keep` is set to `true` so the next non-blank character would be added too

Comment: Your profile says "keen to share knowledge with others ("the best way to learn is to teach" - Frank Oppenheimer)". However you're not teaching, you're giving answers. It would be more useful (for the obvious student/homework questions) to give out advice so they can reach the solution themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String[] charArray = encoded.split(" ");
for(int i = charArray.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--){
    builder.append(charArray[i]);
}
String decoded = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **StringBuffer** to reverse the sentence.Then you can split your sentence word by word using the spaces between the words. After that basic java knowledge ...

```
     String ss = "bxoqb swi eymrawn yim";
     StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(ss);
     String word[] = buffer.reverse().toString().split(" ");
     for (String word1 : word) {
         char c[]=word1.toCharArray();
         for(int x=0;x<c.length;x++){
             if(x%2==0){
                 System.out.print(c[x]);
             }
         }
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
```